# ReactJS cannot seem to call function after page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx, virtual-dom

I need to be able update button class styles after page loads.
Tried doing it in Render() and i have seen people talk about setTimeout and setInterval, but this other way with event is working part of the time

1. ComponentDidMount makes a axios web api call grabs data and in a map all is in render.  I need to check local storage and such, and want to update button color and text, so I tried many things, but then tried window.addeventlistener ... this.handleload

Seems to work only part of the time.... its like it is happening TOO FAST, I don't want to add "hack" like timers, but i'm stuck with no idea how to do this.

I tried calling functions in the render as well.  Not sure why this is so hard to do.

```
handleLoad() {
    alert('always runs from outside loop');

    // loop ONLY runs after refreshing browser several times
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
       //rarely makes it in 
       alert('made it');
       document.getElementById("4534552").classList.remove('btn-warning');
    }
 }

componentDidMount() {

     webApi.get('sai/getofflinemembers?userId=N634806')
            .then((event) => { 
            //........
    }


    // THIS is what i call 
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);

}



render() {

    const contents = this.state.data.map(item => (
        <button id={item.Member_ID} type="button" onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID,e)} 
              className="btn btn-warning">Ready for Download</button>
    )
}
```

I just need to call a function and loop over all the DOM and change it as needed.  Now that has me thinking about react creating a virtual DOM to which i don't know.

Needing to check local storage if a member is already set, then set the class of a bootstrap button to a specific color and text as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: where do you initialize `this.state.data`? Does the `weApi.get().then()` will set the value?

Comment: Could you provide more details about what the axios call and the handleLoad method do ? 
It seems normal to me that the window load event should fire immediately since it is related to the page load.

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned about react it is this... if it feels like it is really hard to do something then that indicates you are probably doing it wrong and fighting the react ecosystem. One of the things to avoid in react is manipulating the raw DOM via `document.getElementById`. You set the className in your render function, so use something like the [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) node module to compute and set classNames on a component.

Comment: is what you define as page is loaded is after you finish calling the `webApi.get('sai/getofflinemembers?userId=N634806')` ? if so, you may call `this.handleLoad()` inside the `.then` hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an advice: If you want to manipulate the DOM, it's better to use `refs` instead of using `document.getElementById`. https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs

But your problem can be solved by using state to store the css class:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    buttonCSSClass: 'btn btn-warning',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        webApi.get('sai/getofflinemembers?userId=N634806')
            .then((event) => {})
            .then(() => this.setState({buttonCSSClass: 'btn'})) // it will update the css class
        }
  }

  render() {
    const { data, buttonCSSClass } = this.state
    return data.map(item => (
      <button
        key={item.Member_ID}
        id={item.Member_ID}
        type="button"
        onClick={e => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID, e)}
        className={buttonCSSClass} 
      >
        Ready for Download
      </button>
    ))
  }
}
```